# Android autofill suggest new password similar to Google Chrome

Tags: android, passwords, autofill

I have a simple create account screen as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:importantForAutofill="yes"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints="username"
        android:hint="email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints="password"
        android:hint="Create a password"
        android:inputType="textPassword">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints="password"
        android:hint="Re-enter password"
        android:inputType="textPassword">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I select the email field the google autofill service suggests a email address to fill. Is there a way to trigger the password manager to suggest a new, secure password? I have seen this behaviour in Google Chrome, is this feature available in native android apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent a good bit of time looking for this one myself, apparently that's a custom feature on chrome(source: [android police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/08/10/android-11-will-make-password-autofill-much-better-thanks-to-keyboard-integration/))

Fingers crossed Google's [androidx.autofill](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/autofill) team